# Post Production Video Effect: How is this done?

Tags: video

I found a YouTube video with a post-production editing effect I'd never seen before. Could someone explain how they did this, and what software they used? Below is the link to a short Loom video.

https://www.loom.com/share/93cf81bf3892480abedcfa3c572ca0b3?sid=60e70cad-2fe3-4e6c-96f5-87bd6651d9c7

They've split the screen area to 2/3 camera and 1/3 text sidebar panel, so smoothly with text fading in. Thanks in advance!! Pavi

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an effect dubbed as "Text Slider" by ArteRamgopal; he has an ~10 minute video tutorial on reproducing it in Camtasia:

.

Comment: Many thanks, Miles Wolbe! That's exactly what I was looking for!! Super cool effect!